# sub string with escape characters and like wildcards

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-like

I have a string `Test_x_x_T1` and i want to replace last three characters i.e `_T1`
if the string contain these three characters otherwise return null. 
the last characters can be `_T1, _T2,_T3`

but i am getting always null

```
select  
case when 'Test_x_x_T1' like '[_]%T_'
then substring(trim('Test_x_x_T1'),1,length(trim('Test_x_x_T1'))-2)
else null end test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Underscore is a wild card for single character search.
If your data contains an underscore ( `_` ), and want to use it as part of your like pattern, then escape it.

**Example**:

```
mysql> select * from (
    ->   select 1 rnum, 'Test_x_x_T1' t
    ->   union all
    ->   select 2, 'Test_x_xT1_'
    ->   union all
    ->   select 3, 'Test_x_xT1'
    ->   union all
    ->   select 4, 'Test_x_x_T1_'
    -> ) tst
    -> where t like '%\_T_';
+------+-------------+
| rnum | t           |
+------+-------------+
|    1 | Test_x_x_T1 |
+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
case when 'Test_x_x_T1' like '%[_]%T_'
```

You need to match the first part of the string, before the '_'.

Comment: i am getting null in your answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you over complicate it.

```
 select  
    case when 'Test_x_x_T1' like '%_T_'
    then substring(trim('Test_x_x_T1'),1,length(trim('Test_x_x_T1'))-3)
    else null end test
```

Comment: it returns value even I have Test_x_xT1

Comment: use literal underscore instead:  '%\[\_\]T_'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`select case when 'Test_x_x_T1' like '%\_T_' escape '\'
    then substr(trim('Test_x_x_T1'),1,length(trim('Test_x_x_T1'))-3)
    else null end from dual`

If you are matching `_` before `T`, you should escape it because `_`  has predefined meaning for like operator.

If `_` is not escaped even this string `Test_x_xT1` will return not null result.